# In ansible how to disable Deprecation warnings for single task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

One of my tasks prints this warning in ansible 2.8

`[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Use errors="ignore" instead of skip. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.`

Is there a way to disable the warning **just for that one task** as I don't want to disable globally via `ansible.cfg`.

BTW the task looks something like this ...

```
- name: Run platform specific tasks
  include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
      #
      # The following ansible 2.8 warning is misleading and fixed later
      #     See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60161
      #
      # [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Use errors="ignore" instead of skip. This feature will be removed in version 2.12.
      skip: true
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to disable the warning for a single task. You could create a special `ansible-no-deprecation.cfg` config file and use this for this special playbook only.

Comment: FWIW, put an empty file *`defaults.yml`* at the end of the list and no skipping/ignoring will be needed.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I like that idea .. is it as idiomatic approach or would it appear strange? I am just a newbie at ansible so I am not clear on "good style".

Comment: Well, I'd say it's idiomatic. The same way as empty *`defaults/main.yml`* in a role. In addition to this *`defaults.yml`* can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no way to avoid this particular DEPRECATION WARNING so just documented why it is there, which for the record is quoting: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/60161

> Un-deprecate skip, as the alternative of errors does not work with with_first_found and only use of lookup

In other words, this is a bug in ansible, with a fix merged to `ansible:devel`.
 Hopefully there is release incorporating this soon and until then I will live with this noise.

*Answering my own question in case this helps someone else.*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, e.g:

```
 - shell: echo something
   args:
     warn: false
```

Comment: I didn’t think this applied in the general case or specifically to the example I quoted in question with *with_first_found* ?